# Only One Order won't show in backend

Tags: magento-1.9, orders

Only one of my Backend orders are not showing as shown in below pictures, Picture 1 is Normal Backend, with Picture 2 showing what I am seeing on only One Customers orders.

This is the First Time it's happened, nothing new has been installed, no updates, no Addons. It doesn't show the Order ID or anything.

[image: Picture 1 - Good Backend View]

[image: Picture 2 - Bad Backend View]

Comment: Any error log? Compare both URL

Comment: if you set admin email id under `system > configuration>sales>emails> order emails` , you can check complete order related information in that mail.....

Comment: Thankyou for your reply. Yes I can view the order and send it to her, but I need to update my backend with completed and automate the invoice/tracking information. I've tried Prashant Valanda's method and will see what it says.
Gopal Patel, I checked error log and nothing showing up regarding this.

Comment: you need to mention their names as tags to send notificiation for them as like @Suranyi

Answer (score 0):

Open your `index.php` file

```
#ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

remove comment from above line and refresh your page have error. You will see error location.

Comment: This is what is shows me, no errors are displayed on that page but opening up the code gives me this;

http://imgur.com/a/Oa5DS